# How to restrict areas to specific types of prisoners

Tags: prison-architect

[image: This is how it looks right now]

So, here we have how my new prison currently looks. However, I ran into issues when it comes to keeping the prisoners to where they belong.

I have 3 cell blocks, the grey ones are currently open to min sec and med sec while i placed all the max sec into another block. I've built them a seperate canteen, a yard, common room, laundry and placed a shower head into each cell. I didn't want to build all these classrooms, chapels and so on just for the max secs, so I want them to be able to leave their block to enter them. But for some reason, the max secs can walk around the prison freely since I don't have a chance to restrict them to specific areas. I've tried to create small areas and make them minsec only or medsec only, but i need both, min and med, to be able to pass through those areas.

Basically, in the image, you can see where the max secs should be able to go, but not further. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your Max Sec prisoners are roaming freely is because all those sections are Shared, which includes the rights for Max Sec to use them.  If you want to stop them mixing in your cell block you should try splitting the sections off with staff only areas.

Personally I think it's a pain that you can't set restrictions for more than one class of prisoner, but maybe someday it will change.

Comment: Unlikely, considering development has stopped for PA. I believe there are mods that kind of do this though.

Comment: Well I tried that, but in that case, I would block the min/medsecs too.^^ Guess I have to build everything twice.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Unless that beta / preview build they put out 2 weeks ago is being dropped then I don't think you're correct there.

Comment: They are only working on bug fixes and general "cleaning up" the game according to the last release video. When the beta gets dropped into the live branch is also the last real update they will be doing. Adding more restrictions to areas does not seem like a bug to me, but rather as a new feature. It is unlikely Introversion will add such a thing to the game.